# MFC: Resource added, but there's still an undeclared identifier for the resource id

Tags: c++, mfc, resources, addition, identifier

I'm trying to add a popup menu to a project, let's call it ProjectA. In VS2010, I would right click ProjectA from the Resource View, and click Add>Resource from the context menu.

Then I would double click the Menu icon, and edit the resource to my wishes. Upon editing this menu, I noticed that I could not edit the ID or file name of the resource. The default name was "IDR_MENU2".

However, I was able to edit the menu items' IDs, such as ID_MENU_COPY and ID_MENU_PASTE.

When I tried to use it in one of the files of ProjectA, I would get an error, "Undeclared identifier", for those IDs.

I even tried to add some resources to the String Table of ProjectA, and those IDs were still invalid when used in the program.

Why is that happening? I'm also quite new to MFC (super beginner).

Comment: Make sure that any cpp files where you refer to those id's, you either directly or indirectly `#include "resource.h"` - that should stop the errors you described.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but instead of adding the whole resource.h I only had to add the bottom line:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include ".\myclass.h"
```

Answer by @Roger Rowland already solves lots though.